# Mysqladmin exit codes

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

Is there a list of exit codes for mysqladmin commands? I checked the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html) but apart from ping command, it does not contain information about exit codes.

I need to know the exit codes of create, drop command as I need to automate few mysqladmin stuff.